# Making a React component "reactive"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following question:
I've made a component mitigating the `switch (){ case 1: case 2:}` behavior. I want my component to be "reactive" to the changes in the State. I'm using Redux. It goes like this:

```
// Switch component
import { Fragment } from 'react'

export const Switch = props => {
    const children = Array.isArray(props.children) ? props.children : [props.children];
    return children.find(child => child?.props.case === props.condition);
}

export const Case = props => {
    return <Fragment>{props.children}</Fragment>;
}
```

further in the views or any other components...

```
// Main.js
export const Main = () => {
    const currentView = useSelector(state => state.currentView);

    return (
            <Fragment>
                    <Switch condition={currentView}>
                        <Case case="view-1">
                            <StartScreen />
                        </Case>
                        <Case case="view-2">
                            <EndScreen />
                        </Case>
                        <Case case="view-3">
                            <OtherScreen />
                        </Case>
                    </Switch>
            </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Providing the store

```
import React from 'preact/compat'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './actions/store';
import {Main} from './components/Main';

export const App = () => {
    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Main />
            </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}
```

Store.js - creating the Store

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {reducer} from '../reducer/reducer';

const middlewares = [
    thunk,
];

export const getCustomStore = (customState) =>
    createStore(reducer, customState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export const store = getCustomStore({});

// This dispatch should only be used outside the preact scope.
// When inside a preact component use "useCustomDispatch()" instead.
export const dispatch = async (...params) => store.dispatch(...params);
```

Reducers

```
import { INITIAL_STATE } from '../constants/INITIAL_STATE';
import { stateModifiers } from '../actions/stateModifiers';

const modifiers = {
    ...stateModifiers,
};

export const createReducer = (initialState) =>
    (state = initialState, action) =>
        modifiers?.[action.type]?.(state, action);

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE);
```

The main problem I'm hitting is that when the `currentView` changes in the state, This component doesn't react to the change. It only works on the initial load.
Any help on that will be highly appreciated, fellows :)

Comment: Can you show your setup please ? how do add the redux provider etc...

Comment: Did you have codesandbox ?

Comment: Hi @JulienKode, I've updated the question. I have action creators, reducer, and the above store, provided by a Provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by just passing the property and using the State selection in the Switch component:

```
// Switch
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Fragment } from 'react'

export const Switch = props => {
    const children = Array.isArray(props.children) ? props.children : [props.children];
    const property = useSelector(state => state[props.condition])
    const matcher = property ?? props.condition;
    return children.find(child => child?.props.case === matcher);
}

export const Case = props => {
    return <Fragment>{props.children}</Fragment>;
}
```

I just brought the state, and by checking, is the condition matches a property in the state. Also, I assume that if the `property` is `undefined`, then the condition should match the string provided in though the props instead checking the state.